# Getting click intercepted on selenium test run on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Does anyone know how to solve such a problem, my 2 main issues are getting a click intercepted error on jenkins (but not when run on eclipse) and getting a timeout due to jenkins being unable to find element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure that the website is accesible in your jenkins server.
2. Check the speed of the code in jenkins server vs eclipse. It might be that the element was not yet loaded and some codes already run. In this case you need to wait for element to lad first, a timeout or the wait functionality of selenium

Comment: will give it a go and see, thank you!